# How can I listen to the table when it is being updated by other jquery or javascript?

Tags: jquery, tr

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="qty">1</td>
            <td class="price">2</td>
            <td class="disc">0</td>
            <td class="total">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td class="qty">2</td>
            <td class="price">10</td>
            <td class="disc">10</td>
            <td class="total">18</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$('#table').on('change', function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var total = 0;
    $('#tr', row).each(function() {
        total += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('.total', row).text(total);
});
```

I am trying to get the code above to work. I am using the latest version of python. I need to listen to a table for a change so that I can get the last row. The row is added by jquery. The rows are added through out the day. I do not know when they will be added. I do not know how many rows will be added either. What libraries do I need to import to get this to work?

Comment: `$('#tr', row).each(function() { ... })` - Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: Why is this tagged with `python`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Why can't you use the code that adds the rows to do what you need? If you don't have access to that code then you can use a Mutation Observer to track rows

Comment: table and it inner elements (tr, td) does not have change events. use setInterval and compare current and previous value of $('#table').html()